# Ant - Import jar from within a zip file

Tags: java, ant, import, jar, build.xml

I want to include a jar file (**ant-contrib.jar**) in my ant build.xml from within a zip. 
How can i do that without unzipping the zip file.
I have tried to use the jarURLConnect.

```
<property url="jar:file:/D:/testing.zip!/testing/ant-contrib.jar" />
```

But this gives me a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

There is no error if I replace "ant-contrib.jar" with a "test.properties" file.

Can anybody please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` tag is for including properties, which would be in a property file. A jar file isn't a property file. The [property docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) are pretty clear.

You need to [unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) the file in order to add it to a classpath, and then actually add it to a classpath: see the [path-like structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) documentation. It's not just a property, though.

Comment: Thanks.. but i thought there would be an easier way without unzipping just like how the properties are included.. The code looks much cleaner that way

Comment: Used the following code to unzip only the jar i need and included in the classpath. Thanks Dave for your help.`<unzip src="${zip.name}" dest="${base.temp.dir}">
    <patternset>
           <include name="testing/ant-contrib.jar"/>
       </patternset>
   <mapper>
           <globmapper from="testing/*" to="*"/>
       </mapper>
  </unzip>`

Answer (score 0):

Check [Unzip Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html).

Answer (score 0):

try "zip" instead of "jar":

`<property url="zip:file:/D:/testing.zip!/testing/ant-contrib.jar" />`

Comment: It displays  "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: zip"

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're doing, but URLs always have two forward slashes as a delimiter. For example, in Subversion you'd do `file://D:/testing.zip!/testing/ant-contrib.jar`.

Now a URL spec in a `<property>` task should point to a [javaspec'd property file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29), so I don't think a jar will work.

What I can tell you is that Java is written so that it can read files inside zips and jars without first unzipping them. There should be no difference in Java if you unzipped `testing.zip` into a directory called `testing.zip` and accessed files from there, or kept it as a zipfile. You should be able to include it in the path name (sans exclamation point):

```
<path id="classpath>
    <pathelement path="D:/testing.zip/testing/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    <yadda, yadda, yadda/>
</path>
```

That should work.

What you can try is to unzip testing.zip into a directory of the same name, and see if you can access the files in `ant-contrib.jar`. Then, try zipping up testing.zip and see if there's any difference. There shouldn't be.

Comment: Hi David, I tried both ways. It is reading the file if "testing.zip" is a folder. But its not able to find the jar if "testing.zip" is a zip file.